# jquery. How to reuse functions with various elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of new to jquery but I'm getting a hang of it. But so far it's been fairly simple jquery.

But I am trying to write a piece of code that is a bit more dynamic

**Function**: I want the code to hide pictures over different times. Like one picture after 2000 milliseconds, then the next after 4000 milliseconds. But I'm still uncertain on a few things...

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="twelve columns" style="padding-top: 24px; text-align:center;">
    <div>
        <img id="1" height="10%" width="10%" src="{{ url('/taskAssets/star.png')}}" />
        <img id="2" height="10%" width="10%" src="{{ url('/taskAssets/star.png')}}" />
        <img id="3" height="10%" width="10%" src="{{ url('/taskAssets/star.png')}}" />
        <img id="4" height="10%" width="10%" src="{{ url('/taskAssets/star.png')}}" />
        <img id="5" height="10%" width="10%" src="{{ url('/taskAssets/star.png')}}" />
    </div>

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4mdQgvGrhwU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <hr>

    <a href="{{ URL::previous()}}">
        <button>Go Back</button>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Row End-->
</div>
</div>
<script>
    var starNumber = 5;
    var star = function() {
        $("#".starNumber).hide("slow");
        starNumber = starNumber - 1;
    };

    setTimeout(star, 2000);
    setTimeout(star, 4000);
    setTimeout(star, 6000);
    setTimeout(star, 8000);
    setTimeout(star, 10000);
</script>
```

I think the source of the issue is here:

```
var starNumber = 5;
var star = function() {
   $("#" .starNumber).hide("slow");
```

am I able to call  $("#" .starNumber)? I tried also  $("#" starNumber) but did not work. How would I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your selector `$("#" .starNumber)` you are not passing a valid string (which jQuery may parse in order to create the appropriate jQuery object). If you are trying to select the element with and id of "5" you must pass the string "#5" to $.

Knowing that the desired form is `$("#5")`, the easiest option in this case is to change the line in question from:

```
// This is syntactically incorrect as you are passing an "#" and
//     the "starNumber" property of... nothing
$("#" .starNumber).hide("slow");
```

to:

```
// This is syntactically CORRECT, as you are concatenating an "#"
//     with the value contained in the "starNumber" variable
$("#" + starNumber).hide("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what is needed.

Answer (score -1):

First, your selector need to be `$('#' + starNumber)` because, JS string concatenation done with `+`.

And if you need a re-usable function, you might use like following:

```
var starNumber = 0, timer, offset = 2000;
var star = function () {
    if ( starNumber == 5 ) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        starNumber = 0;
        return;
    } 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + starNumber).hide("slow");
        star();
    }, offset * ++starNumber);
};
star();
```